# Unable to go to selected URL IEDriver

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I used facebook php-webdriver and downloaded the IE Driver to run the IE, I managed to run the IE but the url wasn't submitted. All other browser was working fine, chrome and firefox only IE is the only problem I have right now. This is error code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'WebDriverCurlException' with message 'Curl error thrown for http POST to http://localhost:5555/session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"internet explorer","platform":"WINDOWS"}} Recv failure: Connection was reset' in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\lib\WebDriverExceptions.php:39 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\lib\remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php(256): WebDriverException::throwException(-1, 'Curl error thro...', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\lib\remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php(177): HttpCommandExecutor::curl('POST', 'http://localhos...', Array, Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\lib\remote\RemoteWebDriver.php(117): HttpCommandExecutor::remoteExecute(Array, Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\lib\remote\RemoteWebDriver.php(63): RemoteWebDriver::remoteExecuteHttpCommand(5000, Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\example.php(7): RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhos...', Object(DesiredCapabilities), 5000) #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\lib\WebDriverExceptions.php on line 39
```

and here is my coding.

```
<?php
require_once('lib/__init__.php');
$host = 'http://localhost:5555/';

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, DesiredCapabilities::internetExplorer(), 5000);

$driver->get('http://google.com/');
$driver->wait(5);
$driver->quit();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

btw , for me the following initialization works, but I'm working on phantomJs:

```
public function __construct($selenium_node_ip)
    {
        $host = 'http://'.$selenium_node_ip.':8080';
        $this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host,DesiredCapabilities::phantomjs(),5000);
    }
```

================

heh , I'm using the folloinwg stack:
selenium  hub + selenim nodes. 
I'm connecting to hub and executing test on a separate noed.
When phantomJs get 'overloaded' it throws the following exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'WebDriverCurlException' with message ' in /var/www/releases/5/application/lib/FB-WebDriver/lib/WebDriverExceptions.php on line 39 WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to http://162.243.171.193:8080/session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"phantomjs","platform":"ANY"}} couldn't connect to host in /var/www/releases/5/application/lib/FB-WebDriver/lib/WebDriverExceptions.php on line 39 Call Stack: 0.0003 638008 1. {main}() /var/www/releases/5/public_html/api/index.php:0 0.0006 664328 2. include('/var/www/releases/5/application/script/api/index.php') /var/www/releases/5/public_html/api/index.php:1 0.0491 6994280 3. FacabookCrawler->__construct() /var/www/releases/5/application/script/api/index.php:20 0.0491 6995920 4. RemoteWebDriver::create() /var/www/releases/5/application/lib/facebookCrawler.class.php:9 0.0492 6997296 5. HttpCommandExecutor->execute() /var/www/releases/5/application/lib/FB-WebDriver/lib/remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:78 0.0492 6997664 6. HttpCommandExecutor::curl() /var/www/releases/5/application/lib/FB-WebDriver/lib/remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:130 0.0500 7000832 7. WebDriverException::throwException() /var/www/releases/5/application/lib/FB-WebDriver/lib/remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:208
```

http://gyazo.com/ac32123059b95483dd53ec9e373f460b

As for now I still didn't find good solution to resolve it, but 
when on the node I   make phantom js restarted using

```
sudo service phantomjs restart
```

http://gyazo.com/ae48dcf945010c28cf41d31c43a08c40

It  works then  OK for me: 
http://gyazo.com/646bf26a48d367bb9e793a847a49de5c

Hope it  somehow helps you to find out the root cause of you problem